# How to pass a new variable to template.xml file

Tags: xenforo

I have installed my own custom theme to xenforo. In my template.xml file i can see the usage of some variable like {$requestPaths.fullBasePath} in the head section. If i want use another variable like these in the header section, where should i defined this variable and from where we can assign values o that variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the controller, something similar to this:

```
$viewParams = array(
    'variableName' => $variableValue,
    'variableName2' => $someOtherValue,
    'someArray' => array(
        'foo' => 'bar'
    )
);
return $this->responseView('MyAddOn_ViewPublic_SomeViewClass', 'some_template', $viewParams);
```

Then in your template, you can use those variables with the curly syntax:

```
{$variableName} // output $variableValue with html escaped
{xen:raw $variableName2} // output $someOtherValue
{$someArray.foo} // output "bar"
```

There are other ways to pass variables to template too: using template_create event listener or <xen:container /> but that's quite complicated. For more information regarding add-on development, read [here](http://xenforo.com/community/resources/categories/development-tutorials.36/).